# how to display a blank space instead of a "0" in the input spring tag

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In my application, i need to have a text field (MNC ID), which is int type,empty while its displayed in the form as a blank space, but instead its appering as "0" as the value.How can i do this?I am using but as i found that i dont have a value tag in the form:input of spring tag, how can i include a value tag in the form:input tag so the i can leave it blank ""? pls help me in this regard

Answer (score 5):

Use type Integer instead of type int.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `PropertyEditor` which would convert `0` to empty string and vice versa. See, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705282/spring-mvc-binding-a-date-field).