# customizing date format using spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i  m encountering the date problem in UI using spring , when i fetch query from database the data format is shown in my UI is `1987-02-12 00:00:00.0` when i submit the values null is going in database . I have used the

`return getJdbcTemplate().update(
                QUERY_CREATE_PROJECT,
                new Object[] { employeeProject.getEmployeeNumber(),
                        employeeProject.getProjectCode(),
                        employeeProject.getStartDate(),
                        employeeProject.getEndDate(),
                        employeeProject.getProjectRole() }) != 0 ? true : false; 
    }` method of spring , my reqiurement is to show date in format (dd/MM/yyyy) and insert the date in same format .How to convert the format of date in our custom date plz help me  and also tell me where to use customization of date , should i customize date in controller layer ,DAO layer or  in service layer

my controller method of creating is

```
  package com.nousinfo.tutorial.controllers;
    import java.util.Map;
    import javax.validation.Valid;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
    import com.nousinfo.tutorial.model.ProjectForm;
    import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.impl.ProjectServiceImpl;
    import com.nousinfo.tutorial.service.model.EmployeeProjectBO;

    /**
     * 
     * @author ankurj
     * 
     */
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("projectController")
    public class ProjectController {
        private ProjectServiceImpl projectServiceImpl;

        public ProjectServiceImpl getProjectServiceImpl() {
            return projectServiceImpl;
        }

        public void setProjectServiceImpl(ProjectServiceImpl projectServiceImpl) {
            this.projectServiceImpl = projectServiceImpl;
        }

        /**
         * Used to set the view 
         * @param id
         * @return
         * @throws Exception
         */
        @RequestMapping(value = "/projectForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView view(@RequestParam("id") int id) throws Exception {
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
            System.out.println(id);
            ProjectForm projectForm = new ProjectForm();
            projectForm.setEmployeeNumber(id);

            modelAndView.addObject("projectForm", projectForm);
            modelAndView.setViewName("projectForm");
            return modelAndView;
        }

        /**
         * Create the project for an employee
         * @param projectForm
         * @param bindingResult
         * @param model
         * @return
         * @throws Exception
         */
        @RequestMapping(value = "/createProject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String createEmployee(@Valid ProjectForm projectForm,
                BindingResult bindingResult, Map<String, ProjectForm> model)
                throws Exception {
            String form = null;
            if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
                return "projectForm";
            }

            model.put("projectForm", projectForm);
            projectForm.setUpdateStatus("A");
            if (projectForm.getUpdateStatus().charAt(0) == 'A') {
                boolean flag = projectServiceImpl
                        .actionDecider(convertprojectFormToprojectBO(projectForm));
                if (flag == false)
                    form = "DBError";
                else
                    form = "Success";

            }
            return form;
        }
        /**
     * This method update the existing  detail of project
     * @param projectForm
     * @param bindingResult
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateProject", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateDepartment(
            @ModelAttribute("projectForm") ProjectForm projectForm,
            BindingResult bindingResult) {

        String form = null;
        projectForm.setUpdateStatus("M");
        if (projectForm.getUpdateStatus().charAt(0) == 'M') {
            boolean flag = projectServiceImpl
                    .actionDecider(convertprojectFormToprojectBO(projectForm));
            if (flag == false)
                form = "DBError";
            else
                form = "Success";

        }

        return form;
    }
```

and this is my model class

```
package com.nousinfo.tutorial.model;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat;

public class ProjectForm {
    @NotNull
    @NumberFormat
    @Min(1)
    private Integer employeeNumber;
    @NotEmpty(message = "project code can't be blank")
    private String projectCode;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private String role;
    private String updateStatus;

    public String getProjectCode() {
        return projectCode;
    }

    public void setProjectCode(String projectCode) {
        this.projectCode = projectCode;
    }

    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Date getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Integer getEmployeeNumber() {
        return employeeNumber;
    }

    public void setEmployeeNumber(Integer employeeNumber) {
        this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
    }

    public String getUpdateStatus() {
        return updateStatus;
    }

    public void setUpdateStatus(String updateStatus) {
        this.updateStatus = updateStatus;
    }

}
```

this is my jsp for date

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>
<script>
    function actionChange(url) {

        if (url == 'Save') {
            document.form.action = "/EmployeeWebSpring/projectController/updateProject";

        }
        if (url == 'Delete') {
            document.form.action = "/EmployeeWebSpring/projectController/deleteProject";
        }

    }

    function home() {
        window.location.href = "/EmployeeWebSpring/search/searchspring";

    }
</script>
</head>
<body background="../images/flower.jpg">
<img src="../images/Header.png" width="1500"/>
<hr width="1500">
    <form:form name='form' commandName="projectForm">
        <fmt:message key="project.searchResult.header" />
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${empty requestScope.projectBO}">
                <fmt:message key="searchResult.noresult" />
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <table align="center">

                    <form:hidden path="updateStatus" />
                    <tr align="center">
                        <th><fmt:message key="employeeNumber" /></th>
                        <td><form:input path="employeeNumber"
                                value="${requestScope.projectBO.employeeNumber}" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr align="center">
                        <th><fmt:message key="projectCode" /></th>
                        <td><form:input path="projectCode"
                                value="${requestScope.projectBO.projectCode}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <th><fmt:message key="startDate" /></th>
                        <td><form:input path="startDate"
                                value="${requestScope.projectBO.startDate}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <th><fmt:message key="endDate" /></th>
                        <td><form:input path="endDate"
                                value="${requestScope.projectBO.endDate}" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <th><fmt:message key="role" /></th>
                        <td><form:input path="role"
                                value="${requestScope.projectBO.role}" /></td>
                    </tr>


                </table>
                <br>
                <center>
                    <table>
                        <tr>

                            <td><input type="submit" name="method" value="Save"
                                onclick="actionChange(this.value)" /></td>

                            <td><input type="submit" name="method" value="Delete"
                                onclick="actionChange(this.value)" /></td>

                            <td><input type="button" onclick="home" value="Cancel" /></td>


                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </center>

            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
        <br />
        <fmt:message key="searchResult.searchAgain" />
        <a href="/EmployeeWebSpring/search/searchspring"> <fmt:message
                key="searchResult.click" />
        </a>


    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the custom editor for Date type, through which you can format the incoming & outgoing date object.This was already explained in the post

[Spring MVC - Binding a Date Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705282/spring-mvc-binding-a-date-field)