# spring mvc post convert Long to Date?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Spring mvc controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Result<String> create(CouponModel model) {//...}

CuponModel:
private Date beginDate;
private Date overDate;
```

when call this api

```
curl -X POST -d '...&beginDate=1459500407&overDate=1459699200' 'http://localhost:8080/coupons'
Error 400 Bad Request
```

first nothing error log output, then changed to `debug` level, ouput

```
Field error in object 'couponModel' on field 'beginDate': rejected value [1459500407]; codes [typeMismatch.couponModel.beginDate,typeMismatch.beginDate,typeMismatch.java.util.Date,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [couponModel.beginDate,beginDate]; arguments []; default message [beginDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date' for property 'beginDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull java.util.Date for value '1459500407'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]
```

How to let parameter long convert to date in model?

I tried below way but it does not work

```
public class StringToDateConverter implements Converter<String, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convert(String source) {
        if (source == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        return new Date(Long.valueOf(source));
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcContext extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
         registry.addConverter(new StringToDateConverter());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add an init binder in your Controller , to tell spring how it should convert the date :

Example:

```
@InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat,false));
    }
```

Comment: yeah, thanks! it works. if the parameter is like this `beginDate=06-04-2016&overDate=10-04-2016` but I want is `new Date(1459500407)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Rafik BELDI! My way is

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {
        public void setAsText(String value) {
             setValue(new Date(Long.valueOf(value)));
        }

    });
}
```

refer to [Spring MVC - Binding a Date Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705282/spring-mvc-binding-a-date-field)