# JDBC Spring4 Java Proper way to convert textbox input to NUMBER and DATE

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, jdbc

I get a 400 error when trying to update a record on JSP web form where the input is coming from a text box. I read that it is likely due to a string to int issue for integers, or a string to DATE issue for dates.

My table look like this:

```
//    Name                                      Null?    Type
//    ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
//    JOB_NUMBER                                NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
//    JOB_NAME                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(200)
//    DROP_CODE                                          VARCHAR2(10)
//    QUANTITY                                           NUMBER(10)
//    MBI_NUMBER                                         VARCHAR2(20)
//    PICKUP_DATE                                        DATE
//    DROP_DATE                                          DATE
//    INHOME_DATE                                        DATE
```

Example of JSP input:

```
<td><form:input path="jobNumber" class="form-control input-sm" value="${row.jobNumber}" cssStyle="width: 99%"/></td>
```

THe update method from the controller:

```
    // C.R."U".D.
    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateWorkPage1Row", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleUpdateWorkPage1RecordRequest(@ModelAttribute("updateRecord") WorkPage1Record record,
                                                    Model model) {
        System.out.println("handleUpdateWorkPage1RecordRequest called.");
        WORK_PAGE_1_SERVICE.updateRecord(record);
        return HOME_PAGE_REDIRECT;
    }
```

excerpt from the Record class:

```
 public int getJobNumber() {
        return jobNumber;
    }

    public void setJobNumber(int jobNumber) {
        this.jobNumber = jobNumber;
    }

 public Date getInhomeDate(){
        return inhomeDate;
    }

    public void setInhomeDate(Date inhomeDate) {
        this

 private int jobNumber;
 private Date inhomeDate;
```

relevant code from the service class:

```
 // C.R."U".D.
    public void updateRecord(@ModelAttribute("record") WorkPage1Record record) {
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        try {
            stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
                    //    Name                                      Null?    Type
                    //    ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
                    //    JOB_NUMBER                                NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
                    //    JOB_NAME                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(200)
                    //    DROP_CODE                                          VARCHAR2(10)
                    //    QUANTITY                                           NUMBER(10)
                    //    MBI_NUMBER                                         VARCHAR2(20)
                    //    PICKUP_DATE                                        DATE
                    //    DROP_DATE                                          DATE
                    //    INHOME_DATE                                        DATE
                    "UPDATE sys.jobs SET "
                            + "JOB_NAME = ?, "
                            + "DROP_CODE = ?, "
                            + "QUANTITY = ?, "
                            + "MBI_NUMBER = ?, "
                            + "PICKUP_DATE = ?, "
                            + "DROP_DATE = ?, "
                            + "INHOME_DATE = ?, "
                            + "WHERE JOB_NUMBER = ?");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("### Could not prepare single insert statement in jobs table", e);
        }
        try {
            // duplicate of what is in the createRecord method
            stmt.setInt(1, record.getJobNumber());
            stmt.setString(2, record.getJobName());
            stmt.setString(3, record.getDropCode());
            stmt.setInt(4, record.getQuantity());
            stmt.setString(5, record.getMbiNumber());
            stmt.setDate(6, record.getPickupDate());
            stmt.setDate(7, record.getDropDate());
            stmt.setDate(8, record.getInhomeDate());
            stmt.executeUpdate();
            commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("### Could not update jobs table record", e);
        }
        try {
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("### Could not close jobs table update statement", e);
        }
    }
```

What is the smallest change to this code that would allow me to correctly handle input from a JSP form so that it is correctly converted into whatever type is specified by the Record class? Previously I had been cheating and just made all of the fields in the table VARCHAR2 to avoid the whole string to mysterious, poorly documented, "DATE" conversion.

Comment: I'm no expert in spring-mvc but I think that you have to link your form with a model object, in your case it would be "updateRecord". First you create or retrieve that object and then show it in the JSP. When you submit the form, the data introduced is bind to that object using converters. I think that Spring got some default converters, maybe you have to configure them. Then you can save that object in the DB.

Comment: Maybe if you put the stack trace that results in the 404 (not 400, I guess) code, people can help you. I've reading about spring-mvc and those conversions should be made automatically. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705282/spring-mvc-binding-a-date-field

Comment: It's not a 404 error. It is a 400 error. Can you provide an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: 400 means BAD request. I think that It got nothing to do with converting types. 404 usually appears when you can't generate the response due to exceptions.Here is an example of a form that includes dates, it may help you http://www.journaldev.com/2668/spring-mvc-form-validation-example-using-annotation-and-custom-validator-implementation