# Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.LocalDate

Tags: java, spring, jackson

Here I am Using LocalDate class of java 1.8.In my bean I took return type as LocalDate. And I am sending date formate as `07/01/2017`. when I am trying to save that I am getting follwing exception.

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] (default task-33) Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.LocalDate] from String value ('07/01/2017'); no single-String constructor/factory method
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@39959f38; line: 1, column: 650] (through reference chain: com.pro.bean.ParentBean["Soici"]->com.pro.bean.Soici["fecha_de_solicitud"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class java.time.LocalDate] from String value ('07/01/2017'); no single-String constructor/factory method
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@39959f38; line: 1, column: 650] (through reference chain: com.pro.bean.ParentBean["Soici"]->com.pro.bean.Soici["fecha_de_solici"])
```

Comment: seems to me a issue of Spring propertyeditor issue. Look that up and you will find helpful info online

Comment: look at this answer this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14052884/4828463 This answer uses @InitBinder which allows you to set your own editor instead of propertyeditor

Answer (score 5):

Add com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype-jsr310 dependency

Then configure Jackson2ObjectMapper with

```
 @Bean(name = "OBJECT_MAPPER_BEAN")
    public ObjectMapper jsonObjectMapper() {
        return Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json()
                .serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) // Don’t include null values
                .featuresToDisable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS) //ISODate
                .modules(new JSR310Module())
                .build();
    }
```

SOURCE: https://blog.oio.de/2015/06/13/add-support-for-java-8-date-time-api-to-jackson-serialized-rest-web-services/

Comment: Depending on how he's configuring (Boot, in particular), he may just need to add the dependency.

Comment: why do we need to follow this much of stuff for only Local date

Comment: @Ravi: The `java.time` libraries were introduced in Java 8. Presumably compatibility with them are kept in dependencies to enable people who are using older versions to not include them.

Comment: Just to add to @J11 answer notice that  `JSR310Module` is deprecated since Jackson 2.5 so better use  `JavaTimeModule`