# org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerEx‌​ceptionResolver

Tags: java, json, spring

reff:-[this is my related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518051/can-not-instantiate-value-of-type-simple-type-class-java-time-localdate)

If I add `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype-jsr310` dependency I am getting Following exception. And where do I need to configure `@Bean(name = "OBJECT_MAPPER_BEAN")`

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerEx‌​ceptionResolver] Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableExc‌​eption: Could not read document: Text '07/01/2017' could not be parsed at index 0 (through reference chain: com.caja.pro.bean.ParentBean["Soicitud"] nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Text '07/01/2017' could not be parsed at index 0 (through reference chain: com.pro.bean.ParentBean["Soicitud"]->com.caja.pro.Soicitud["‌​fecha_de_solicitud"]‌​)
```

Comment: Please edit your original question, no need to open a new one.